# Failure in installing elementary Files from appcenter

Tags: release-hera, pantheon-files, applications, appcenter, files

I am using eos hera 5.1
When I try to install **Files** from **appcenter** it fails with a response
I tried installing some other apps and they work fine

```
The package id's '' are not valid
```

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: Sounds similar to this issue: https://github.com/elementary/appcenter/issues/460.  Have you tried running `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in a terminal and then restarting?

Comment: Tried that already and didn't work. Still the same

Comment: Try running `appstreamcli dump io.elementary.files | grep pkgname` in a terminal. It should find a `<pkgname>pantheon-files<\pkgname>` tag. If this is missing or empty it would give rise to your error.  It is OK for me on both a stable and daily install of elementary Hera.

Comment: tried it and got the reponse
`<pkgname>pantheon-files</pkgname>`. Its not missing but the issue still persists

Comment: Can you run `pkcon resolve pantheon-files` and post the output?

Comment: I have flagged this in the appropriate elementary Slack channel - I am out of ideas at the moment.